# Trying to extend Facebook oauth token using Koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, facebook-graph-api, koala

In reference to:

http://rubydoc.info/github/arsduo/koala/master/Koala/Facebook/GraphAPIMethods#graph_call-instance_method

http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

---

My code looks something like this:

```
fb = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
fb.graph_call("/oauth/access_token", {"client_id" => app_id, "client_secret" => app_secret, "grant_type" => "fb_exchange_token", "fb_exchange_token" => access_token })
```

Although the return value contains the extended token but it is throwing MultiJson::DecodeError

```
MultiJson::DecodeError: 387: unexpected token at 'access_token=long-lived_token&expires=5184000]'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/json-1.6.1/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/json-1.6.1/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/multi_json-1.0.3/lib/multi_json/engines/json_gem.rb:13:in `decode'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/multi_json-1.0.3/lib/multi_json.rb:65:in `decode'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/koala-1.3.0/lib/koala/api.rb:61:in `api'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/koala-1.3.0/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:421:in `graph_call'
from (irb):7
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I suspect the ending `]` that is causing the error. Not sure if this is a Facebook error or mis-handling on my part. Appreciate if someone could help me out. Thank!

---

I also tried using Net::HTTP.get(uri) instead. But got the below error.

```
Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `read_nonblock'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2211:in `read_status_line'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2200:in `read_new'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1183:in `transport_request'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1169:in `request'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1073:in `request_get'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:394:in `block in get_response'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:393:in `get_response'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:370:in `get'
from (irb):11
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@dotcloud/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Not sure if it's a firewall or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the OAuth `exchange_access_token_info` method:

```
oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("consumer_token", "consumer_secret")
oauth.exchange_access_token_info("auth_token")
```

P.S. I also got the error you did doing it your way. The problem is that Koala expects the body of the response to be in JSON format, but in this special case it's actually name/value pairs in URL (query string) format, e.g.:

```
access_token=[...]&expires=[...]
```

Comment: What exactly do these variables "consumer_token", "consumer_secret" and "auth_token" refer to? None of them are references to anything what John Lee provides in his question.